# Python wheel file with private artifactory

Tags: python-3.x, setup.py, python-wheel

I am preparing a wheel file where it should use private artifactory instead of pypi.

My folder structure

```
project
  .config
     pip
       pip.conf
   src
    __init__.py
   setup.py
   requirements.txt
```

pip.conf

```
[global]
index-url = http://username:password@domain/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple
timeout =
trusted-host =
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
  requirements=f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='My First Setup File',
    version='1.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires = requirements 
)
```

```
Python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

It is giving me wheel file but when i want to install using pip install *.whl it is referring to pypi.org not the private artifactory which I mentioned in the pip.conf.
Not able to understand what is going wrong